# Using if else statement with json values in jsoncpp

Tags: c++, codeblocks, jsoncpp

I am trying to do something similar using `jsoncpp` inside a function which returns json values as strings.

```
std::string some_function(std::string val){
.
.
.
if(val=="date")
{
    Json::Value my=root["data"]["date"];
    std::cout<<"Date";
}
else if(val=="id")
{
    Json::Value my=root["data"]["id"];
    std::cout<<"ID";
}
else if(val=="art")
{
    Json::Value my=root["data"]["article"];
    std::cout<<"Article";
}
else
{
    return "Error";
}
//Json::Value my=root["data"]["date"]; //this works
return my.toStyledString();
}
```

I am able to successfully run json values example: `Json::Value my=root["data"]["date"];` outside the if else statement(comment out code) but when i tried to run these json values inside an if-else-if statment it shows this error

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: *warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]* implies your function has a path that does not return.  Can you past a actual [mcve]?

Comment: This way `my` doesn't exist when you exit `if/else` statements. Try to add `Json::Value my;` before `if/else` and then just `my=root["data"]["article"];`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's not the only error you get, you should get errors that `my` isn't defined or declared anywhere too.

That's because you have many variables `my` but each is defined only in its own scope, and none declared in the function scope. Since there is no such variable you get a follow up variable because of the first error.

The solution is very simple: Declare *one* variable before the `if`-`else if`-`else` chain and use only plain assignment:

```
Json::Value my;

if(val=="date")
{
    my=root["data"]["date"];
    std::cout<<"Date";
}
...
```

---

On an unrelated note, that's not how I would write such a function. I would probably do something like

```
std::string some_function(std::string val)
{
    static std::string const valid_values[] = { "date", "id", "art" };

    if (std::any_of(std::begin(valid_values), std::end(valid_values),
                     [&](auto const& s)
                     {
                         return s == val;
                     }))
    {
        return root["data"][val];
    }

    return "Error";
}
```